# How to bind span value to model in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form where I need to use to buttons(plus and minus) to set count, but I can't figure out how can I bind this counter to model.

I have model looks like:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Name {get; se;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
}
```

Also I have view with form looks like:

```
@model SushiJazz.Models.ViewModels.OrderViewModel
<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateOrder", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "basket-form" }))
    {
        <div class="basket-form__input-line">
            <label for="b-name" class="basket-form__label">
                Name <span class="star-req">*</span>
            </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name, new { @class="basket-form__input", @id="b-name", @type="tel", @autofocus="autofocus"})
        </div>
        <div class="basket-counter order-counter static">
            <span class="add-del-btn blue">-</span>
            <span class="basket-counter-number">2</span>
            <span class="add-del-btn blue">+</span>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

So, How can I bind my basket-counter to Model.Count property?
Is it posible?

Comment: I suppose there is a js piece somewhere which updates the count when someone click plus and minus. Right?

Comment: You need to assign the value to a hidden input for the property 
 - e.g.  `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Count)` (and use javascript to handle the buttons and increment the value)

Comment: @Andrei, Yes, of course.

Comment: `<span class="basket-counter-number">2</span>` => change this to readonly `TextBoxFor`/`HiddenFor` as counter and bind `span`'s increment/decrement element with `change` event to add/subtract the value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks again)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>@Model.Name</span>
```

And hide the texbox data like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
```

Try this, I have used this in my project and it is working fine.

Comment: please use <span>@Model.Name</span>